# Call me (on/at/in) the day of delivery?

Tags: grammar

*"Please call me (**on/at/in**) the day of delivery"*. Which is correct?

Comment: Hi Yalpsid, welcome to English Language & Usage (ELU). Note that ELU is a question and answer site for *linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts*. The best place to ask questions about basic English is at [ELL.se]. For further information about what's expected on our EL&U site, see **[Ask]**.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for the question is as below:

Please call me on the day of delivery.

"ON" is used as a preposition to indicate days, weekends, streets and avenues.

This is suggesting a lightly specific detail of the information.

A more specific sentence would be written as:

Please call me in Bangalore, on the day of delivery at 1 PM.